# XSL: Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method

Tags: java, xml, pdf, xslt, xalan

I got XSL file which i'm trying to generate over my app.

The code goes like this:

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Source styleSheetLoc = new ResourceSource(styleSheetLocation);
Templates t = factory.newTemplates(styleSheetLoc);  // <<< throwing the Exception       
return t.newTransformer();
```

The exception is:

```
ERROR:  'Cannot find external method 'com.am.caretalks.util.XsltUtils.getResourceString' (must be public).'

FATAL ERROR:  'Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'com.am.caretalks.util.XsltUtils.getResourceString(node-set, node-set, int)''

javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'com.am.caretalks.util.XsltUtils.getResourceString(node-set, node-set, int)'

    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:990)

    at com.am.caretalks.sendreport.CreatePDF.buildTransformer(CreatePDF.java:1147)

    at com.am.caretalks.sendreport.CreatePDF.createProviderEngagementPDF(CreatePDF.java:608)

    at com.am.caretalks.sendreport.CreatePDF.createProviderEngagementPDF(CreatePDF.java:586)

    at com.am.caretalks.admin.EngagementReportExportServiceImpl.exportAndUpload(EngagementReportExportServiceImpl.java:131)

    at com.am.caretalks.admin.EngagementReportExportServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$38327504.invoke(<generated>)
```

**EDIT:**
This is the called function from the XSL file
    public static String getResourceString(final String messageKey, final String locale, final String customerIndex) {
    .
    .

```
}
```

I searched the web and I found a solution that tells me to use only objects (not primitives) while calling to a function from my XSL file to my java code and due to that i'm getting these error, but nothing did helped me here.

The big issue here that I don't understand what is the error and how to solve it, what do I need to do according the thrown Exception?

Any other suggestions to fix this issue are welcome

Comment: Somewhere in your stylesheet there is a call to the external function `com.am.caretalks.util.XsltUtils.getResourceString`. You need to find that call and tell us what the supplied arguments are.

Comment: @MichaelKay
I've edited the question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that you are passing inappropriate arguments to the function. It appears the method expects (string, string, string) and you are passing (node-set, node-set, int). I don't know Xalan well, but try doing an explicit conversion of the supplied arguments to the required type by calling number() or string().